# using a for loop for web scraping - cannot "pass" certain data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following code is supposed to scrape the rating and the date the rating was posted.

The issue here is, that employees answers the negative reviews, and the date of their post is scraped as well. So when I scrape the site, there's an uneven number of ratings and dates (20 ratings vs 24 dates), as four of the dates belong to the answers given by employees.

In the code I try to "pass" every time the class "ugc-brand-response" shows up which is for the employee answers. So if no ugc class is met "pass" and if not just continue - but none of the data gets stored. Not even the first couple of reviews.

I've learned so much from reading other peoples questions and answers. Thanks for this awesome community.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/reviews/jabra-elite-85h-wireless-noise-canceling-over-the-ear-headphones-black/6335100?variant=A"

url_get = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(url_get.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'lxml')


rating_n_date=[] 

for rating in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "c-review-average"}):     
    rating_n_date.append(rating .text)
for date in soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"submission-date"}):
    if "class" == "ugc-brand-response" in date:
        pass    
    else:
        continue
    rating_n_date.append(date.text)
time.sleep(2)
print(rating_n_date)
```

Here's the data including the :

```
<li class="review-item" tabindex="-1"><div class="row"><div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3"><div class="undefined ugc-author v-fw-medium body-copy-lg">Jimmy</div><ul class=" ugc-badge-list"><li class="visible-xs-inline-block visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"><span class="c-overlay-wrapper"><span class="overlayTrigger"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ugc-badge-overlay-bf28b82b-76f5-3c85-897e-598a91bbd8a8-0" aria-owns="ugc-badge-overlay-bf28b82b-76f5-3c85-897e-598a91bbd8a8-0" data-track="Custom"><div class="ugc-my-bby-badge"><img alt="My Best Buy® Member" src="https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/ugc-raas/ugc-common-assets/ugc-badge-mybby-core.svg"></div></button></span><span></span></span></li></ul></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9"><div class="c-ratings-reviews v-medium"><p class="sr-only">Rating: 2 out of 5 stars</p><span class="c-stars c-stars-medium" alt="40%" aria-hidden="true"><span class="unfilled"></span><span class="filled" style="width:40%"></span></span><span class="c-reviews"><span class="c-review-average" aria-hidden="true">2</span></span></div><h3 id="review-id-bf28b82b-76f5-3c85-897e-598a91bbd8a8" class="ugc-review-title c-section-title heading-5 v-fw-medium  ">A disappointment: low volum, weak bass, distorts</h3><div class="disclaimer">Posted <time class="submission-date" title="Apr 28, 2019 11:29 PM">3 months ago</time></div>
```

Here's the code I don't want - the employee answer:

```
<ul class="ugc-brand-response-list"><li><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3"><div class="ugc-brand-response"><h4 class=" c-section-title body-copy-lg v-fw-medium  ">Brand response</h4><p class="body-copy-lg">Jabra</p><div class="disclaimer"><time class="submission-date" title="Apr 29, 2019 8:46 AM">3 months ago</time></div><div class="ugc-brand-response-body body-copy-lg"><p class="pre-white-space">
Hello Jimmy - We were sorry to learn that the Jabra Elite 85h did not meet your expectations.  As the Elite 85h is a relatively new product, it is very important that you update the firmware in the headphones as often as necessary to keep up-to-date.  We are constantly improving all aspects of the Elite 85h through firmware updates.  If you have any specific questions or concers, we invite you to contact us directly by completing the web form at&nbsp;<a href="https://www.jabra.com/ServiceMenu/contact/ContactJabraSupport/ContactJabraSupportConsumer" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" style="word-break: break-all;">https://www.jabra.com/ServiceMenu/contact/ContactJabraSupport/ContactJabraSupportConsumer</a>, or by giving us a call - we love to help!  Thank you.
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stratos-logos/logos/Jabra.jpg" alt="Jabra" title="Jabra" style="display: block !important; margin-top: 2em !important; border: 1px solid #ccc !important; padding: 2px !important; background-color: white !important;">
<!--[if ReviewResponse]><![endif]--></p></div></div></div></div></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never skip over where a class is `ugc-brand-response-list`, because you explicitly pull everything with class attribute `submission-date`

You also have `continue` misunderstood. When you use `continue`, it doesn't mean what you would think it should mean, in the sense of "continue on with the code". What it really means is, "stop right here. Don't follow with the rest of the loop. Go to the next item." So in the way you have it in your code, when it DOESN'T find `class == "ugc-brand-response"`, it goes to `else`, which says `continue`. So it'll never append to your list, which is why your data isn't stored/appended.

What you could do, is go to the parent tags and pull the whole review "block" which is found with the class attribute `"col-xs-12 col-md-9"` , and then from there, go into each of those and pull out the rating and submission date together using `find` (`find` will get the 1st occurrence of what ever you are looking for, which means it won't grab the date of the employee replies), and then store those in to a list. I then just threw it into a dataframe/table.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/reviews/jabra-elite-85h-wireless-noise-canceling-over-the-ear-headphones-black/6335100?variant=A"

url_get = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(url_get.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'lxml')


rating_list = [] 
date_list = []

for ratings in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "col-xs-12 col-md-9"}):     
    rating = ratings.find('span', {'class':'c-review-average'}).text
    submission_date = ratings.find('time', {'class':'submission-date'}).text

    rating_list.append(rating)
    date_list.append(submission_date)


data = {'Rating':rating_list, 'Date':date_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
   Rating          Date
0       5  3 months ago
1       5  2 months ago
2       4  3 months ago
3       3  3 months ago
4       4  3 months ago
5       4  3 months ago
6       5  3 months ago
7       4  3 months ago
8       5  3 months ago
9       4    1 week ago
10      4  3 months ago
11      2  3 months ago
12      5  3 months ago
13      4     1 day ago
14      4   1 month ago
15      4  3 months ago
16      4   3 weeks ago
17      2  3 months ago
18      3   3 weeks ago
19      5  3 months ago
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. Whenever I feel like I almost had it, I really don't. I have still much to learn.

Comment: @doomdaam just keep at it. practice, practice, practice. It gets easier as you pick up little things (I thought `continue` and `pass` worked the way you were using it too when I first was learning...I mean it makes logical sense, right!?). But it's actually the opposite - `pass` means continue on your way, and `continue` means pass on this item...seems so illogical, but it is what it is i guess.

Comment: thanks for the words of encouragement. I'll learn it eventually